# border-image it not showin the image

Tags: css

I'm trying to use an image to show in the right border of a div but is not shown

```
border-image: url("/images/products/line.png");
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
```

Comment: You are missing the border-color

Comment: Try setting `border-color: transparent;`

Comment: also, dont you need to put more after your image path. see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Comment: example in URL is `border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to set the border as transparent:

```
border-color: transparent;
```

And don't forget to set the position of the image. Something like:

```
border-image:url("/images/products/line.png") 30 30 repeat;
```

Comment: I added  `border-color: transparent;` but only a dot on the right down corner is shown

Comment: You need to set the position of the image within the border. Look at the example at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/border-image